# Escaping parenthesis in Pig declare statement

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

[image]**PIG VERSION**: 0.12.0-cdh5.10.1

I am fairly new in using pig. I learned that there are several ways to define parameters in pig. One of them is 'declare' statement. Just wanted to know, if we can use characters like "(" and ")" (parenthesis) in the parameter value. I am trying to save few(variable for different feeds) lookup values in the declare statement which might contain "(" and ")" characters due to which it is throwing error. I also tried to escape these characters using **"\"** and **"\\"** but it does not seem to work
For example,
On running below statement in pig:

```
%declare DESC 'Joe\\(s URL'
```

Getting below error on trying to read the same using below command:

```
sh echo $DESC
```

**ERROR:**

```
2018-02-25 10:11:55,692 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 8, column 13.  Encountered: "(" (40), after : ""
```

But, this approach of escaping is working fine for characters like "%" and "=" which are mentioned on the below page:

https://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution

Is there any way to escape such characters like "(" and ")" in the declare statement? I noticed the same case is with " ' " also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though parentheses don't require escaping in Pig declare statements. See this toy example:

```
%declare DESC 'Joe(s URL'
A = LOAD ...
B = LIMIT A 2;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE '$DESC' AS var;
dump;

(Joe(s URL)
(Joe(s URL)
```

I was also able to pass parameters with parentheses to Pig through the command line, e.g.:

```
pig -f temp.pig -p DESC='Joe(s URL'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems like I was testing it wrong. 'sh echo $var' is not the correct way to test it as it is throwing error, but using the same declared variable in the code is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think `sh echo $var` is usually a good way to test parameter substitution, but in this particular case the parenthesis required escaping in bash but not Pig, so `sh echo $var` failed even though the parameter substitution was successful in Pig.

Comment: After some more testing, it seems like `sh echo "$var"` works where `sh echo $var` and `sh echo '$var'` don't. Maybe something to do with declaring `var` using single quotes and then encasing it in double quotes to pass to bash.

Comment: I tried with all the 3 options, you have mentioned but getting error in all three. I have attached the screenshot along with the question above. Let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Interesting! I don't doubt you're getting an error - I suspect it has to do with different versions of Pig since I'm testing in 0.16 and you're using 0.12. Maybe it's a bug that's been fixed in more recent versions.

Comment: Yes, seems like the issue is with the pig version. Anyway, my current problem is resolved. Thanks a lot for your help 